# How can'i clear the cache WebElement list in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

can anyone help me please, it is possible in Java to clear the cache elements located by Selenium every execution?

I'm testing an application which do not have access to the HTML code and whose components have not fixed ID (are dynamic), so I need to recover the elements through its content, not only that, the url of the application does not change, because the components are generated via ajax / jQuery.

So when using a xPath that has already been used on another occasion, the selenium does not perform a new search and always returns the same element.

Below the xpath I use to locate the Enter button on a page:

```
 WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Entrar')]"));
```

If you use the X page and repeat the same path on page Y, always get the page element X. How do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any exception thrown saying element could not be found. May be in your case element in page y could not be located by webdriver and so the previous element still remains.

Comment: throws no exception, and always returns the same element found in the first use of xpath. It is possible that Selenium does not find the element because the url of the application does not change, I believe that the components are "loaded" via Ajax / JQuery entire application execution is displayed on the main page, the URL starts and ends on localhost: 8083

Comment: You can try storing null in the element before searching for the element in page y. Even then if it doesnot work may the element in page x still in the DOM even in page Y. You have to verify its DOM if there are two elements with same content. So by default selenium will fetch only the first element or you have to specify which nth element you need.   findElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Entrar')]"))[n];

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the code to find element each time you want to use that element.

```
findElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Entrar')]"));
```

So each time you use the element, the new element in the Page is found.

Comment: run findElement every time, but always returns the same element. I would like to clear the cache to force the search every time that I need to use the xpath

Comment: Then do find element on the same variable but with the new xpath